Failed to create email confirmation callback link in ASP.NET Blazor
I have successfully created email confirmation link and sent email in ASP.NET Core using following call back link. However when I do it in Blazor, IUrlHelper doesn't work well:
var callbackUrl = _Url.Page(
   "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
   pageHandler: null,
   values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = "~/" },
   protocol: _request.Scheme); 

I have tried using some website suggestion to register services as following but still got error.
Now I just want to switch to Blazor NavigationManager to create the callback link.
Can anyone suggest how to use NavigationManager to create the call back link? Thank you very much.

Tried some website sugesstion to register services as following but still got error
`   services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped(factory =>
{
var actionContext = factory.GetService()
.ActionContext;
return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
});
`
Failed  with error  Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'actionContext')

According to your description, you could try to use  NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters method to achieve your requirement.
The usage for this is like below:
@code {
    private string? message;
    private ApplicationUser user = default!;
    private string? email;
    private bool isEmailConfirmed;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "change-email")]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
        email = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        isEmailConfirmed = await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);

        Input.NewEmail ??= email;
    }

    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
    {
        if (Input.NewEmail is null || Input.NewEmail == email)
        {
            message = "Your email is unchanged.";
            return;
        }

        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, Input.NewEmail);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
            NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmailChange").AbsoluteUri,
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["email"] = Input.NewEmail, ["code"] = code });

        await EmailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, Input.NewEmail, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));

        message = "Confirmation link to change email sent. Please check your email.";
    }

    private async Task OnSendEmailVerificationAsync()
    {
        if (email is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
            NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmail").AbsoluteUri,
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["code"] = code });

        await EmailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, email, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));

        message = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "New email")]
        public string? NewEmail { get; set; }
    }
}


Yes That is correct answer. Thanks for your help. I can't vote for my questions. sorry.

Any other error when you use my codes?
